# Process to upload multiple image associated with a unique id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a simple small application in which user will add its vehicle and 5 images associated with that vehicle and the vehicle description is inserting in table1 and images is inserting in table2 associate with vehicle id of table1.

The problem i am facing in that is i have one form to upload vehicle description and images too.
How could we get vehicle id at the same time of uploading images.

Comment: You get the vehicle_id when you insert the details into table 1, then use that as a value in table 2? I don't understand how this can be a problem?

Comment: wat u hv tried so far?

Comment: problem is at the time of image upload we dont have correct vehicle id because description not inserted yet. these are the process which have to be triggered at same time

Answer (score 0):

programmatic way can be to:

- add a UNIQUE INDEX to the field
- generate a random string in PHP
- loop in PHP ( while( ! DO_THE_INSERT ) )
- generate another string

**Note:**

This can be dirty, but has the advantage to be DBMS-agnostic
Even if you choose to use a DBMS specific **unique ID** generator function (UUID, etc) it is a best practice to assure the field HAS to be UNIQUE, using the index
the loop is statistically not executed at all, it is entered only on insert failure

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1= "INSERT INTO vehicle ( vehicle_type,...)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["vehicle_type"]."', ...)";
        if($result1 = mysql_query($query1))
        {
            $vehicle_id = mysql_insert_id();

            $query2= "INSERT INTO vehicle_pic_details ( vehicle_id, pic1, pic2, ...)
            VALUES ('".$vehicle_id."', '".$_POST["pic1"]."', '".$_POST["pic2"]."',...)";

            if($result2 = mysql_query($query2))
            {
                //success msg
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..the process is user upload the images first to server then we click on post button to insert the descripltion..

Comment: u will get image_id wen u adding description..isnt it?

Comment: yes but that image id should be associated with the vehicle id that is not generated yet b'cause the description is not inserted...these are the two process which should be triggered at same time..

Comment: there is no error in code error in process..once i upload pictures in server then user click on post so how do we get vehicle id because it is the one which is generated on post click

Comment: u post description -> then u hv to generate vehicle_id and then u have to add that descitpion with vehicle_id,description, image_is..is this ur flow?

Comment: no my flow is uploadimage->upload multiple images on server->then post description. This is the problem when i upload images i dont have vehicle id.

Comment: should i store images path in session and insert after Post description??